# How to focus a perspectie or orthographic Camera on GameObject(s)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, scale

What exactly is Unity doing so that when you press F to focus within the Scene view camera frame, on the entire 3D object no matter its scale?

How can one replicate this camera positioning at runtime, for arbitrarily scaled 3D models?

To clarify: I am not asking about how do you move the camera - I am asking about how do you position the camera so that it can include the entire extent of the entire 3D object, no matter its scale. (Sometimes, for imported models the scale is arbitrarily small or large, for example).

(For either perspective of orthographic camera.)

Comment: @gguney updated - hope it's more clear. please provide comments for improvement before downloading.

Comment: How would one "position the camera" but not "move the camera"? For an orthographic camera, just moving it might not be sufficient to fit the model into the frame (since moving the camera farther away has no effect), so are you interested in resizing the camera's orthographic size in that situation?

Comment: There is also the case where the camera is within the bounds of the object. So it is definitely positioning

Answer (score 3):

#### Perspective

For a perspective 3D camera (with rotations) you can use the following method (slightly adopted from [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fit-object-exactly-into-perspective-cameras-field-of-view-focus-the-object.496472/))

```cs
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool TryGetBounds(this GameObject obj, out Bounds bounds)
    {
        var renderers = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
        return renderers.TryGetBounds(out bounds);
    }

    public static bool TryGetBounds(this GameObject[] gameObjects, out Bounds bounds)
    {
        var renderers = gameObjects.Where(g => g).SelectMany(g => g.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>()).ToArray();
        return renderers.TryGetBounds( out bounds);
    }

    public static bool TryGetBounds(this Renderer[] renderers, out Bounds bounds)
    {
        bounds = default;

        if (renderers.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bounds = renderers[0].bounds;

        for (var i = 1; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            bounds.Encapsulate(renderers[i].bounds);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Facto how far away the camera should be 
    private const float cameraDistance = 1f;

    public static bool TryGetFocusTransforms(this Camera camera, GameObject targetGameObject, out Vector3 targetPosition, out Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        targetPosition = default;
        targetRotation = default;

        if (!targetGameObject.TryGetBounds(out var bounds))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var objectSizes = bounds.max - bounds.min;
        var objectSize = Mathf.Max(objectSizes.x, objectSizes.y, objectSizes.z);
        // Visible height 1 meter in front
        var cameraView = 2.0f * Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * camera.fieldOfView); 
        // Combined wanted distance from the object
        var distance = cameraDistance * objectSize / cameraView; 
        // Estimated offset from the center to the outside of the object
        distance += 0.5f * objectSize; 
        targetPosition = bounds.center - distance * camera.transform.forward;

        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(bounds.center - targetPosition);

        return true;
    }

    public static bool TryGetFocusTransforms(this Camera camera, GameObject[] targetGameObjects, out Vector3 targetPosition, out Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        targetPosition = default;
        targetRotation = default;

        if (!targetGameObjects.TryGetBounds( out var bounds))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var objectSizes = bounds.max - bounds.min;
        var objectSize = Mathf.Max(objectSizes.x, objectSizes.y, objectSizes.z);
        var cameraView = 2.0f * Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * camera.fieldOfView);
        var distance = cameraDistance * objectSize / cameraView;
        distance += 0.5f * objectSize;
        targetPosition = bounds.center - distance * camera.transform.forward;

        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(bounds.center - targetPosition);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like e.g.

```cs
public class FocusController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;
    public GameObject[] targets;

    private Vector3 _targetPosition;
    private Quaternion _targetRotation;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        if (!_camera)
        {
            _camera = Camera.main;
        }

        _targetPosition = transform.position;
        _targetRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (_camera.TryGetFocusTransforms(targets, out var targetPosition, out var targetRotation))
            {
                _targetPosition = targetPosition;
                _targetRotation = targetRotation;
            }
        }

        _camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_camera.transform.position, _targetPosition, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
        _camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_camera.transform.rotation, _targetRotation, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

#### Orthographic

For orthographic a slightly modified version from [here](https://gist.github.com/RyanNielson/9879056)

```cs
public class OrthoFocusController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] targets;
    [SerializeField] private float _minimumOrthographicSize = 0.01f;
    [SerializeField] private Camera camera;

    [SerializeField][Min(1f)] private float spacingFactor = 1;

    private Vector3 _targetPosition;
    private float _targetSize;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!camera) camera = Camera.main;

        _targetPosition = camera.transform.position;
        _targetSize = camera.orthographicSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            // Using the extensions from above
            if (targets.TryGetBounds(out var bounds))
            {
                _targetPosition = bounds.center;
                _targetPosition.z = camera.transform.position.z;

                _targetSize = CalculateOrthographicSize(bounds);
            }
        }

        camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(camera.transform.position, _targetPosition, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
        camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(camera.orthographicSize, _targetSize, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private float CalculateOrthographicSize(Bounds boundingBox)
    {
        var orthographicSize = camera.orthographicSize;

        Vector2 min = boundingBox.min;
        Vector2 max = boundingBox.max;

        var width = (max - min).x * spacingFactor;
        var height = (max - min).y * spacingFactor;

        if (width > height)
        {
            orthographicSize = Mathf.Abs(width) / camera.aspect / 2f;
        }
        else
        {
            orthographicSize = Mathf.Abs(height) / 2f;
        }

        return Mathf.Max(orthographicSize, _minimumOrthographicSize);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

*Model Credits*

> Original model:
> Electronic Arts
>
> Conversion:
> http://gfx-3d-model.blogspot.com
> free3dart@gmail.com